# How to escape whitespace using csc.exe (.NET built in C# compiler)

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

Like the title says, how do I escape white space passed in a file name to csc.exe? Caret's cannot be used. For example, file path `C:\Users\user name\My Documents\file.cs` I would normally do `C:\Users\user^ name\My^ Documents\file.cs` but since carets cannot be used, it throws an error. I've tried wrapping the path name in double quotes but no luck. Any help?

Comment: Very murky when you don't explain exactly how you invoke csc.exe.  Support is already built into the .NET framework, best to use it instead of cooking your own.  Use CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

Answer (score 0):

This is a general OS issue, not the compiler.

When you have spaces in a path, you enclose it in `"`:

```
csc <other parameters> "C:\Users\user name\My Documents\file.cs"
```

Answer (score 0):

The caret character (^) is not recognized as an escape character or delimiter. The character is handled by the command-line parser in the operating system before it is passed to the argv array in the program.

A string enclosed in double quotation marks ("string") is interpreted as a single argument, regardless of white space that is contained within. A quoted string can be embedded in an argument. So as mentioned by Oded enclode it in ".

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd.aspx